# Performance Indicators for Load Testing?

Tags: testing, jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing

Currently I am working my way into the topic of load and performance testing. In our planning, however, the customer now wants to have indicators for the load and performance test named. Here I am personally however over-questioned. What exactly are the performance indicators within a load and performance test?

Comment: Just to name a few: average response time, requests per second/minute, CPU usage, memory usage.

Comment: Ahhhh thanks I almost thought so, but in the first moment I couldn't classify it properly anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate the Performance indicators based on Client Side and Server Side Indicators:

**1. Client Side Indicators :** [JMeter Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

```
    Average Response Time
    Minimum Response Time
    Maximum Response Time
    90th Percentile
    95th Percentile
    99th Percentile
    Throughput
    Network Byte Send
    Network Byte Received
    Error% and different types of Error received

    Response Time Over Time
    Active Threads Over Time
    Latencies Over Time
    Connect Time Over Time

    Hits Per Second
    Codes Per Second
    Transactions Per Second
    Total Transactions Per Second etc.

    You can also obtain Composite Graphs for better understanding.
```

**2. Server Side Indicators :**

```
    CPU Utilization
    Memory Utilization
    Disk Details
    Filesystem Details
    Network Trafic Details
    Network Socket
    Network Netstat
    Network TCP
    Network UDP
    Network ICMP etc.
```

**3. Component Level Monitoring :**

```
   Language Specific likes Java, .Net, Python etc.
   Database Server
   Web Server
   Application Server
   Broker Statistics
   Load Balancers etc.
```

**Just to name a few.**